# InvalidOperationException: Collection Was Modified

Tags: c#, exception, collections, dictionary

I know that I can't modify a collection while iterating over it.

Normally I make a copy of the collection I want to iterate over, then iterate over the copy to avoid errors.

My program; however, makes lots of fast modifications to the collection I'm trying to make a copy of.

Could the error be occurring because I am making a copy while the parent collection is being modified?

I know ConcurrentDictionary provides some sort of locking mechanism for cross threading. Is there something similar I can use to prevent this error?

```
    // Original collection:
    Dictionary<string, Enemy> Dict_Enemies = new Dictionary<string, Enemy>();

    // Copy of original collection: (this line throws the exception)
    Dictionary<string, Enemy> Dict_Enemies_Copy = new Dictionary<string, Enemy>(Dict_Enemies);
```

Comment: Why not using a [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) for `Dict_Enemies`?

Comment: When I use a ConcurrentDictionary, my program just seems to hang where the exception normally would have been thrown. Perhaps I have a problem elsewhere.

Comment: You can use the [ConcurrentDictionary.ToArray()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287109.aspx) method to make a copy of it in a *thread-safe* manner. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) for `Dict_Enemies` to allow it to be modified from multiple threads. Then make a copy of it in *a thread-safe operation* using the [ToArray()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287109.aspx) method:

```
// Original collection:
var Dict_Enemies = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Enemy>();

// Thread-safe copy:
ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, Enemy>> Dict_Enemies_Copy = Dict_Enemies.ToArray();
```

Comment: please note that the handling of ConcurrentDictionary is non-trivial by itself - you have to change some code as some operations (add for example) on a CD might return "false" because of concurrency issues - in which case you have to retry the operation! CD is nice but not if you haven't encapsulated your access already

Comment: @CarstenKönig Agreed. Switching to a `ConcurrentDictionary` will certainly require some changes in the way items are added/removed. However, there are [multiple ways to approach the problem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997369.aspx), depending on the requirements.

Comment: I think this solved my problem thank you. When I remove a key from a concurrentdictionary can I use a dummy object for the 'out' parameter? Dummy foo; Dict.TryRemove(key, out foo);

Comment: @JeffSchweigler The [ConcurrentDictionary.TryRemove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287129.aspx) method returns the object that has been removed in an `out` parameter when the operation succeeded or `default(TValue)` when it failed. You must pass an argument for it, since it's required by the compiler, but you don't have to use the actual result, if you don't need it.

Comment: You don't have to create a copy of a `ConcurrentDictionary` in order to safely iterate it because they're already safe to iterate. If they weren't, then the `ToArray` method wouldn't work either!

Comment: @Gabe True. I assume the OP has some other requirements that make it preferable not to modify the original dictionary.

Comment: @EnricoCampidoglio: OP Explicitly states "I make a copy of the collection I want to iterate over, then iterate over the copy to avoid errors" so it sounds like making a copy isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

A `Dictionary<K,V>` does not support multiple concurrent writers, which means you must already have a lock. Just make sure that you create your copy while holding that lock.

Comment: I don't have a lock for sure because I'm not sure how to implement one correctly. If I use 'lock(dictionary) { //dosomething// }', won't it cause the other parts of my program to stop working correctly because they won't be able to access the dictionary?

Comment: I need some sort of a way to lock the dictionary, but have other methods check for a lock, wait for it to be unlocked, and then continue.

Comment: I tried locking the copy while I iterate over it, but I still get the exception...

Comment: If you don't lock the dictionary *every* time you use it (with `lock (dictionary)` for example), your code is not correct. It may work, but only because you're lucky!

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate this dictionary as a private member of a class, and use a lock (with the same lock object in both places, possibly the dictionary itself) to ensure that writes and copies don't happen at the same time.  Don't allow direct access to the dictionary anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

But similar code is perfeclty working for me.....Could you give more explanation of your code???

```
  Dictionary<int, Test> dicOrg = new Dictionary<int, Test>();//Original
  dicOrg.Add(1, new Test() {id= 1,name="name",add="add"});
  Dictionary<int, Test> dicCopy = new Dictionary<int,Test>(dicOrg);//Copy of dicOrg
```

Comment: I have various methods removing items and adding items to dicOriginal at the same time.

I have various methods making copies of dicOriginal at the same time.

I get the exception at multiple locations wherever I try to make a copy of dicOriginal.